# Monte Carlo simulator

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am having trouble creating my own Monte Carlo simulator with python 3... I am trying to predict the future price in the upcoming year. I am still learning how to program in python.

My data:

```
Price = np.array([29429,30426,32513,40605,52806,57581]) 
Year = np.array([1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975])
```

Attempted Monte Carlo Simulator..

```
N_pts_per_fit = 30
indices= random.randint(0,Price,N_pts_per_fit)
for i in range[N_pts_per_fit]:
    newdata = indices
```

Let me know if I am posting questions correctly and feedback on my approach. 
Thank you and have a great day!

- Bob

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. what happens when you run your code? what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Not like I am an expert in Monte Carlo method, but can it even be used to predict trends?

Answer (score -1):

Range should have parentheses:

```
range(N_pts_per_fit)
```

and are you wanting to store each newdata? I assume you have more code in the for statement

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to post a comment but would still like to help - thanks for your input though

Comment: Yes my problem is I want to store new data. This is all I have so far but still looking for the right notation to do monte carlo in python.

Comment: You could store the newdata as a list, so the final line could be like

Comment: `newdata.append(indices)` if newdata is setup as `newdata = []`